# Index of array containing key value pair in JSON file

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

How would I write a function that searches a JSON file to find the index where there exists an object containing a particular key-value pair?  For example, the function would return `0` for the following JSON document if we were looking for `value: '100.0'` because `key1` rests at index `0`.

```
var object = {
    key1 : {
        name : 'xxxxxx',
        value : '100.0'
    },
    key2 : {
        name : 'yyyyyyy',
        value : '200.0'
    },
    key3 : {
        name : 'zzzzzz',
        value : '500.0'
    },
}
```

Comment: Just notice your `var object` is not an array but a(n) (javascript) object. Learn more http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/qskt9Lg9/

```
function findInJson(key1, value) { //pass it the desired matching key value pairs
    var i = 0;
    for (var key in object) {  //this will iterate through key1 - key3
        var current = object[key];
        if (current[key1] == value) {
            return i; //return the index
        }
        i++;//increment if no found
    }
   return -1;
}
```

and you would just call it like so:

```
findInJson("name", "xxxxxx")
```

This site: http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-jsonarray-in-javascript/ gives you a lot more info on how to parse JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed a key in your object will not be deleted and added later you can use:

```
function (object, key, value) {
    var index = 0;

    for (var oKey in object) {
        if (object[oKey][key] === value) {
            return index;
        }

        index++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

But [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement iterates over an object in an arbitrary order. See: "Deleted, added or modified properties" section for detailed explanation.

It would be better to use an array and fit "keyN" into your {name, value} object if you want the order to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in supporting IE8 and below, then you could use the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method like :

```
function getIndex(val) {
    for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(object).length; i++) {
        if (object[Object.keys(object)[i]].value === val) {
            return i;
        }
    };
    return -1;
};
console.log( getIndex("100.0") ); // returns  0
console.log( getIndex("500.0") ); // returns  2
console.log( getIndex("800.0") ); // returns -1
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qezbLqkd/1/)**